# LINQ Entities Where clause not in correct place

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Apparently I'm  missing something with how LINQ to entities works.  Hopefully one of you all can educate me.

Please try the below locally and let me know if you are seeing the same results.  Something is really strange here...

Lets look at a very simple LINQ expression using navigation properties.

This was generated in LinqPad in a C# statement.

```
var result = (from ge in group_execution
                where ge.automation_sequences.project.client_id == 1 && ge.parent_group_exec_id != null
                select new
                {
                    ge.id,
                    ge.parent_group_exec_id,
                    ge.automation_sequences.project.client_id
                });
result.Dump();
```

OR, we can use joins...which will lead to the same bad results, but lets continue...

```
var result = (from ge in group_execution
            join aseq in automation_sequences on ge.automation_sequence_id equals aseq.id
            join p in project on aseq.project_id equals p.id
            where p.client_id == 1 && ge.parent_group_exec_id != null
            select new
            {
                ge.id,
                ge.parent_group_exec_id,
                p.client_id
            });
result.Dump();
```

These very simple LINQ expressions generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Filter1].[id1] AS [id], 
    [Filter1].[parent_group_exec_id] AS [parent_group_exec_id], 
    [Extent5].[client_id] AS [client_id]
    FROM    (SELECT [Extent1].[id] AS [id1], [Extent1].[automation_sequence_id] AS [automation_sequence_id], [Extent1].[parent_group_exec_id] AS [parent_group_exec_id]
        FROM   [dbo].[group_execution] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[automation_sequences] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[automation_sequence_id] = [Extent2].[id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[project] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[project_id] = [Extent3].[id]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[parent_group_exec_id] IS NOT NULL) AND (1 = [Extent3].[client_id]) ) AS [Filter1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[automation_sequences] AS [Extent4] ON [Filter1].[automation_sequence_id] = [Extent4].[id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[project] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[project_id] = [Extent5].[id]
```

This baffles me.  For the life of me I can't understand why LINQ is doing this.  It's horrible, just look at the execution plan:

[image]

Now lets manually clean this up in SSMS and view the correct SQL and execution plan:

[image]

Much better, but how do we get LINQ to act this way?

Is anyone else seeing this?  Has anyone else ever saw this and corrected it and if so how?

Thanks for looking into this.

---

**UPDATE, attempting Chris Schaller fix:**

```
var result = (from ge in group_execution
                select new
                {
                    ge.id,
                    ge.parent_group_exec_id,
                    ge.automation_sequences.project.client_id
                }).Where(x=>x.client_id == 1 && x.parent_group_exec_id != null);
result.Dump();
```

Just so you all know I'm monitoring the SQL through SQL Server Profiler.  If anyone knows of any issues doing it this way let me know.

[image]

---

**UPDATE, a fix for JOINS, but not nav properties, and a cause, but why?**

Here's your solution:

```
var result = (from ge in group_execution.Where(x=>x.parent_group_exec_id != null)
            join aseq in automation_sequences on ge.automation_sequence_id equals aseq.id
            join p in project on aseq.project_id equals p.id
            where p.client_id == 1// && ge.parent_group_exec_id != null
            select new
            {
                ge.id,
                ge.parent_group_exec_id,
                p.client_id
            });
result.Dump();
```

[image]

Null checks shouldn't cause the framework to mess up like this.  Why should I have to write it this way?  This just seems like a defect to me in the framework.  It will make my dynamic expressions a little bit more difficult to write, but maybe I can find a way.

Navigation Properties still mess up...so I'm still really sad.  Picture below:

```
var result = (from ge in group_execution.Where(x=>x.parent_group_exec_id != null)
                where ge.automation_sequences.project.client_id == 1// && ge.parent_group_exec_id != null
                select new
                {
                    ge.id,
                    ge.parent_group_exec_id,
                    ge.automation_sequences.project.client_id
                });
result.Dump();
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, these optimizations are responsibility of the SQL query optimizer / execution plan builder. EF (as well as any developer) is expected to provide a **valid** SQL statement. How is that SQL statement shouldn't matter - RBOs are gone nowadays.

Comment: Try to focus on the actual problem. Does this query shape cause you any problems w.r.t. performance? It's common knowledge that EF (or any ORM) doesn't produce the queries a human being would construct carefully. But usually they do a decent job. Also, EF works on better query generation all the time, so in the next version your own optimizations may turn useless (may even have adverse effects).

Answer (score 0):

move your where clause to after you have defined the structure of the select statement

```
var result = (from ge in group_execution
            select new
            {
                ge.id,
                ge.parent_group_exec_id,
                ge.automation_sequences.project.client_id
            }).Where(x => x.client_id == 1 && x.parent_group_exec_id != null)
result.Dump();
```

Comment: No luck, i've updated the original post with the results of this approach

Comment: Why would this make any difference to the SQL generated?

Comment: I see, actually that new execution plan is more efficient, it is correctly filtering the parent group on the inner query which reduces unnecessary index seeks on records that will be filtered out. Unfortunately you wont get much cleaner output than that without specifying the select yourself. The way that the parser separates the extents is a neccessary evil that we acccept when using Linq-to-entities. What is important is the execution plan now should be close, the extra seeks to join the data in memory between the extents should not add a measurable overhead to the runtime.

Comment: @DavidG are you kidding? OP was kind enough to show exactly how this affected the generated SQL. Thanks spyder1329 ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Remember that Linq-to-entities flattens the results of queries to execute as SQL and then hydrates the object graph from those results.

When your query uses navigation properties or joins the query parser has to allow for zero results from those sub queries (*Extents*) to make sure that all columns that are required in the output *and any interim processing* are represented. By explicitly specifying a filter on a table for != null early in the query the parser knows that there is no further possibility that the field and any relationships linked by that field will be null, until then the parser prepares the query as if the joins will return null results

> It is worth checking, but i wonder if *UseDatabaseNullSemantics* has anything to do with this?

Try:

```
dbContext.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = false
```

---

In Linq, we can specify Where clauses as often as we like, improve the resulting SQL we should filter early in the query and granularly.

The parser engine is optimized to follow and implement your query sequentially, and generate good SQL at the end of it. Don't try to write linq-to-entities the same way that you structure your SQL, I know it's counter intuitive because the syntax is similar

> A good technique is to assume that before each clause all the records from the previous statements have been loaded into memory, and that the next operation will affect all of those records. So you want to reduce the records before each additional operation by specifying a filter before moving on to the next clause

In general, if you have a filter condition based on the root table, apply this to the query before define all other joins and filters and even selects, you will get much cleaner sql.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I'm going to include the true end result I'm after in all of this in the original post.  I basically an an optional EXISTS statement in the where clause.  This statement needs to reference a field in the original select statement in order to run faster, but since LINQ is creating these new WHERE clauses it's hard for me to control the behavior.